# Keyboard key fix for right arrow key?

Tags: windows, keyboard

My right arrow key doesn't work anymore. Maybe it's a hardware failure but is there an easy workaround maybe a software key remapping? I have tried to open my pc to no avail.

Comment: If you are asking for a software solution, please include some tags to show what OS you use.

Answer (score 1):

Use [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

It will let you map keys or key combinations.

For example, holding alt whilst press left arrow might suffice as a new map.

Something like

```
 !Left:: Send ^{Right}
```

[This post](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/76430-altcontrol-arrow-remap/) is about mapping the cursors.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great little tool called `SharpKeys`.
It will write the mapping directly into the registry and thus the mapping will work in the login screens as well (unlike AHK which will kick in only after you've logged in).

AHK is a great tool though, I use it everyday for a wide variety of tasks.

[Here](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) you can download sharpkeys.

[image: This image shows the remapped keys.]